# Define semantic size for \DeclarePairedDelimiter

Tags: delimiters, mathtools, size, semantics

To better separate content and presentation, how can I define semantic sizes for the optional sizing argument to `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`?

Here are two attempts to define "bulkysize" as `\Big`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\params}{X, Y, Z; a, b, c}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\roundbr}{(}{)}

% Attempt 1
\newcommand*{\bulkysize}{\Big}
% Attempt 2
\newcommand*{\bulkysizeoption}{[\Big]}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y &= f \roundbr[\Big]{\params}
    && \text{Intended result}
    \\
  y &= f \roundbr[\bulkysize]{\params}
    && \text{Attempt~1: Doesn't resize as intended}
    \\
  y &= f \roundbr\bulkysizeoption{\params}
    && \text{Attempt~2: Doesn't parse as intended}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Failed attempts]

"Why not just use `\Big` directly?" Well, some time later I might decide I want "bulkysize" to be `\bigg` instead. I don't want to have to go through all my code and manually change `\Big` to `\bigg`. "Isn't that just a simple Find and Replace?" No. Not all instances of `\Big` correspond to "bulkysize" brackets. E.g. I might have `\Big` inside a TikZ figure label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that `\roundbr` determines the size of the delimiters by doing

```
\@nameuse{<reduced optional arg>l}<left delimiter>
<material>
\@nameuse{<reduced optional arg>r}<right delimiter>
```

if the optional argument is present; if the optional argument is `\Big`, then the backslash is stripped off and `<reduced optional arg>` becomes `Big`.

However, with `\bulkysize` you get

```
\@nameuse{bulkysizel}
```

that's equivalent to `\relax`. Define the required commands.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand*{\params}{X, Y, Z; a, b, c}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\roundbr}{(}{)}

\newcommand{\bulkysize}{\Big} % just for completeness
\newcommand{\bulkysizel}{\Bigl}
\newcommand{\bulkysizer}{\Bigr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  y &= f \roundbr[\Big]{\params}
    && \text{Intended result}
    \\
  y &= f \roundbr[\bulkysize]{\params}
    && \text{Resizes as intended}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]